# How to enlarge a gene map plot?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'm doing gene sequence analysis, and I've a genome for which I've plotted the genes and their proteins, but the plot is very busy and when I knit my R markdown to present the image it's cut off. Not sure where to start on how to adjust this, any help would be appreciated. Here is the code for it:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(devtools)
install_github("wilkox/gggenes")
library(gggenes)
gene_prediction <-read.csv('~/genome1table.csv', header=TRUE, sep=',')
gene_names<-c(gene_prediction$Gene)
starts <- c(gene_prediction$Start)
ends<-c(gene_prediction$End)
strand<-c(gene_prediction$Strand)
genome_name<-rep('Genome',62)

dfgenome1map<-data.frame(genome_name=genome_name, name=gene_names, start=starts, end=ends, category=category, strand=strand)

dfgenome1map$direction<- ifelse(dfgenome1map$strand == "+", 1, -1)

ggplot(dfgenome1map, aes(xmin=start, xmax=end, y='', 
           fill=category, 
           label=gene_names, forward= direction)) + 
  geom_gene_arrow() +
  geom_gene_label(align = "center") +
  labs(x='locus (bp)', fill='VOG category')+
  theme_genes() + 
  scale_color_continuous() +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_blank(),
    axis.title.x=element_text())
```

This then looks like this in my R markdown but the key of proteins should be bigger:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you paste the chunk here ?

You can adjust the plot size with :

```
opts_chunk$set(fig.width = 15, fig.height = 15)
```

15 is an example of a high value.
You have chunk options on the top right corner in the last version of RStudio.

What is the output file ? HTML/docx/pdf ?

You can also specify options in the begining of the .Rmd (the YAML) :

```
---
title: "xxx"
output:
  html_document:
    fig_width: 15
    fig_height: 15
    fig_caption: true
---
```

Comment: the output is html

Comment: It seems this work for changing the graph I have straight after my gene map but my gene map stays the same. I am putting pts_chunk$set(fig.width = 15, fig.height = 15) above my ggplot(dfgenome1map, line, is that correct?

Comment: You can try to change the options in the YAML (header of the Rmd file).